# Retrieving a PHP variable with jQuery?

Tags: php, variables, jquery

How can I retrieve a PHP variable from jQuery? If I am using a jQuery POST function such as this:

```
$.post("login.php", {username:username, password:password}, function(data){
    $('section').html(data);
});
```

Instead of showing 'data' is it possible to show a certain PHP variable from the PHP file to output?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean... if you `echo` out the contents of your variable then that's what `data` will contain.

Comment: data is the result of your ajax call (login.php) you just need to display the php variable you want in your php script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

login.php:

```
<?php

echo 'hello';
```

would then return `hello` as the contents of your `data` variable in the ajax call. JS cannot directly access PHP variables, unless PHP choses to output those variables' contents via the response to the ajax call. If you need to pass back multiple variables/values, then use a JSON container:

```
<?php

echo json_encode(array('hello' => 'there', 'how' => 'are', 'you' => '?'))
```

would give you 3 pieces of data ('hello', 'how', 'you') which contain 'there', 'are', and '?', respectively. You'd access them as `data['hello']`, `data['how']`, `data['you']`.

Comment: I have a little problem, how do I get that array in jQuery? When I get to the part $.post("login.php", {username:username, password:password}, function( before I would just write data so what do I do this time? Sorry I'm not very good with jQuery yet.

Comment: since you're passing `data` into a `.html()`call in your sample, you'd want your PHP script to just output HTML.  The json stuff was just to show how to pass back multiple different bits of data in a way that you could retrieve the individual bits easily.

Comment: But what if I wanted to output more than just one thing? So using my example if I logged in then I would want to lets say show a variable called $page in the login.php file which is what I want the page's content to change to (the html). But I also want to change a certain part in the header and that part in the header has an id of "options", I can't change this part of the header in the PHP file so I want jquery to get that variable and change that part of the header. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

"data" in your example is just whatever your PHP script returns back.  So if you want, you can easily just return back (by printing) only the value you are interested in.

For example, if you login.php script simply needs to return back "TRUE" or "FALSE" for if they logged in successfully, then in your PHP script simply say:

 `if (logged in correctly) 
   print "TRUE";
 else
   print "FALSE";`

Then in your jQuery, just test to see if "data" is the string TRUE or FALSE as in:

  `if (data == "TRUE") {
    // do stuff.
  }`

If you're trying to return back more than just a single value, then I would suggest you use a JSON object in both PHP and jQuery, but I will leave those details for other posters...

Answer (score 0):

`var jQueryVarFromPhP = <?=$phpVariable;?>;`

Just my 2 pennies